# How to loop through integers from a given txt file and find 2nd largest number in c?

Tags: c, file

I have given a txt file that contains barcodes of product. I have to find which barcode is the second largest among the barcodes and have to tell how many times it has appeard in the file.

for example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 8
```

[I have to search from a big txt file that has more than 100 barcodes]

my output should be

Second largest barcode in terms of number : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0 7

It has appeard 3 times.

I have done so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int one  ,two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, ele, twel;
    int one2  ,two2, three2, four2, five2, six2, seven2, eight2, nine2, ten2, ele2, twel2;

    char temp[256], name[30];

    FILE *in;
    if((in = fopen("bar.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int finalcount = 0;
    int max;

    while (!feof(in))
    {
        fscanf(in, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",&one, &two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine, &ten, &ele, &twel);
        count++;
        //to print all the barcodes:
        //printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",one ,two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, ele, twel);

        while((!feof(in)))
        {
            max = finalcount; // trying to find the maximum count first. 
            fscanf(in, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",&one2, &two2, &three2, &four2, &five2, &six2, &seven2, &eight2, &nine2, &ten2, &ele2, &twel2);
            if(one == one2 && two == two2 && three == three2 && four == four2 && five == five2 && six == six2 && seven == seven2 && eight == eight2 && nine == nine2 && ten == ten2 && ele == ele2 && twel == twel2);
            {

                if(finalcount > max)
                {
                    max = finalcount;
                }
                finalcount++;

            }

            if (feof(in)) 
            break;

        }

        if (feof(in)) 
            break;
    }

    fclose(in);
    //printf("Count2 %d",count2);
    printf("Final count %d ", finalcount);
    printf("Max count %d ", max);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to take one line of the numbers and try to compare it with the rest. But it doesn't work properly.
I am very new at file handeling, I think I have problem in my logic as well a code structure.
is there a better way to write the code of the problem?

Comment: Is the input file sorted ?

Comment: You've used `feof` four times in two nested loops, and you don't need it at all. You can control the loop with `while(fscanf(in, "%d %d ...)) == 12) { ... }` Then build a 64-bit number from the digits, and compare in a typical way.

Comment: @pifor no, input file is not sorted

Comment: ...but it would be easier to read one string with a loop controlled by `fgets` and build a 64-bit number from the string (skipping every other character). You don't need a variable for each digit.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you please give an example, or give me a source where I can learn it? I have searched from some website but they only show how to write or copy from a file

Comment: `char buff[100]; while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, in) != NULL) { ... }`. The barcode digit *characters* are now in an array at `buff[0]`, `buff[2]`, `buff[4]` etc.

Comment: I understand. Then I have to use atoi(buff) to convert them in integers, is that correct? and how to skip whitespaces, Sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal in these simple steps(assuming barcode is in number format):-

1. Open your file in read mode and check for any error while opening the file.
2. Read numbers from your file and store them in an array.
3. Sort the array in ascending or descending order.
4. According to your sorting technique either `array[1] in descending order` or `array[n-2] in ascending order` will be the `second largest barcode`.
5. Now, using a loop count the appearance of that barcode in the array.
6. Print your output.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

// There are 10 no. inside barcode.txt
void bubbleSort(long int *array, int n)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if(array[i] <= array[j])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

// main()
int main()
{
    FILE *barcode;
    long int buffer[SIZE], second_largest = 0;
    int i = 0, appearance = 0;

    barcode = fopen("barcode.txt", "r");
    if( !barcode )
    {
        perror("barcode.txt");
        exit(-2);
    }
    // Storing data into buffer.
    while(fscanf(barcode, "%ld", &buffer[i++]) != EOF);

    // Sorting buffer in descending order.
    bubbleSort(buffer, SIZE);

    second_largest = buffer[1];
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if(second_largest == buffer[i])
            appearance++;
    }
    printf("Second largest barcode %ld appeared %d times in the file.\n", second_largest, appearance);
    fclose(barcode);
    return 0;
}
```

**File contains:**

```
21467
17283
27653
9019
26069
13826
19323
20289
13516
14657
```

**Output:**

```
Second largest barcode 26069 appeared 1 times in the file.
```